# Большое количество однотипных запросов

Tags: url, request, android, java

Здравствуйте уваждаемые! Есть такой вопрос. Пишу приложение для android и столкнулся с необходимостью получать информацию о файлах по url. Необходимо получить разсмер файла по URL. Как это сделать я знаю. Делаю примерно так

```
private int getFileSize(URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        conn.getInputStream();
        return conn.getContentLength();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return -1;
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Все замечательно, но этот способ хорош только для небольшого числа url. Проблема в том чтло у меня их 800. Поэтому обычный цикл по всем url с выполнением запроса по каждому выполняется очень долго. Есть ли какие то варианты ускорить этот процесс? Может можно как-то отправлять сразу по несколько url или еще что-то такое? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Это Вам надо сервер научить отдавать всю нужную информацию скопом.

Comment: Можно попробовать асинхронный вызов с пулом потоков (если эти 800 вызовов независимые), ускоритесь в ~threadPoolSize раз.

Comment: Это если сервер не будет против :-)

Comment: если подробнее то речь о vk api и получении информации об аудиозаписях. Насколько вообще возможно получение данных о размерах файлов за адекватные сроки в этом случае?

Comment: Тут всё упирается не в производительность клиента, а сервера. И его желание (как правильно отметил @Чад) предоставлять вашей данные пачками.

Лучше делать это официальным способом. Посмотрите, есть ли в официальном VK API такое.